# Accept-Ranges doesn't appear in asp.net response

Tags: asp.net

I wrote a simple asp.net page that simulates file download response. I added the following lines to adjust response:

```
    Response.AddHeader("ETag", "\"" + _EncodedData + "\"");
    Response.AddHeader("Last-Modified", lastUpdateTiemStamp);
    Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");

    //Set the ContentType
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

    //Add the file name and attachment, 
    //which will force the open/cancel/save dialog to show, to the header
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + dItem.FileName);

    //Add the file size into the response header
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", (endByte - startBytes).ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

My problem is that Accept-ranges doesn't apear in the response header, but when I change Accept-Ranges to Accept-Ranges1 this header(Accept-Ranges1) will receive a response header.

This problem only occurs when I am debugging the project in Visual Studio. When I am on IIS everything is ok

Comment: Which webserver, IIS Express, ASP.NET Development Server or a different one? How do you determine it doesn't show up in the response? Do you use a proxy server that may remove the header?

Comment: My IIS is on windows 2008 r2 and my development is on visual studio 2008 I dont know which versoin of iis vs use but i am on windows7. I read header with http analyzer